# IntelliJ Idea Bash Support - Recognize functions, defined in other shell scripts

Tags: bash, intellij-idea

I use IntelliJ Ultimate with BashSupport to write buildscripts in Bash for my projects. When I write a shell script, which calls a function, which is defined in another shell script, this function is not highlighted and recognized by the IDE.

Same with global variables.

scripts.sh looks like

```
#!/bin/bash
. "common/remote.sh" 

echo "do something"
dosomething "foo"
```

common/remote.sh looks like

```
#!/bin/bash

function dosomething {
    echo $1
}
```

Is there a way to tell the plugin or IDE to recognize those function from other scripts?

Comment: What version are you using? This works fine to me in Intellij IDEA 2017.2.2.

Comment: I use IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2.6

Comment: @MathiasMethner https://github.com/jansorg/BashSupport/issues may be a better place for this issue.

Comment: Thanks CrazyCode. My Post is about the question, if I use the IDE wrong. If it should work, of course I will check for bug reports or submit one.

Comment: Any progress here? This limitation is really annoying.

Comment: No, no progress yet.